# Distribution Upgrade, Not Enough Free Disk Space

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 17.10

I am trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 but I get this error, and I dont know what to do as It does not point out where the problem is.

[image: the error I get]

I think I have enough disk space in / , /boot , and my home folder so I don't know why I still get this error.

partitions and free spaces:

[image: partitions and free spaces]

can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried running `apt autoremove` to see if you have any unused packages taking up space?

Comment: Is it possible that the disk space is filled doing first stages of upgrade, it fails, and then cleans up the used space? Doesn't Ubuntu show the disk space needed for the upgrade in the UI?

Comment: @andrybak yes I tried autoremove and clean and autoclean, no success after those. And to answer your second question, no I did not see anything mentioning the space needed for update ...